# Why is it OK to only use brackets for annotation array argument, but not for method parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, java-annotations

OK, so there's something that bothers me a little in the Java syntax that I don't quite understand.

When an annotation accepts an array as one of its argument's value, we can do so by providing the values inside a couple of brackets, like so:

```java
public @interface SomeAnnotation {
  String[] someParam();
}
```

```java
@SomeAnnotation(someParam = { "foo", "bar" })
public class Example {}
```

This is a very neat and concise way of passing an array of values. Love it.

But the same can not be done when calling a method:

```java
public interface Example {
  public static void someMethod(String[] someParam) {
    // Do something
  }
}

// ...
Example.someMethod({ "foo", "bar" }); // Syntax Error :(
```

From the look of it, both the annotation's `someParam` and the method `someParam` are declared as a `String[]` array.

I suppose its related to the way annotation are handled by Java under the hood, and/or the fact that `someParam` is declared like a kind of method (with parenthesis at the end) in `SomeAnnotation`, but still... why?

If someone out there could shed some light on this, I would be very grateful.

*Please note that I'm not looking for alternatives or workaround, but rather some explanations.*

**Subsequent question**

I know I could call the method with the `new String[]...` syntax, like so:

```java
Example.someMethod(new String[] { "foo", "bar" });
```

But that also seems strange to me since the param is supposed to be an array of `String` and the values inside the brackets are indeed `String`s. I would expect the compiler to be able to match things up and be OK with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple explanation is that this is the way that the Java language was specified. Designing the syntax for a new programming language is a compromise between expressiveness and conciseness versus simplicity / readability and non-ambiguity.

The basic Java syntax is what they arrived at in ~1995. From then onward, the Java designers have been constrained by the implicit requirement that any changes to the language syntax must not "break" older code<sup>1</sup>.

Annotations are actually a case in point.  The `@ <Identifier>` syntactic marker creates a new context where new rules will not interfere with older parts of the Java syntax.  This allowed them to use a simpler / cleaner way of writing "array literals" in the new context.  So they did.  But they couldn't do the same thing more generally<sup>2</sup> without creating parsing problems and/or breaking old Java code.

---

<sup>1 - Or that any breakages should be minimal.  For example, changing `enum` to a keyword in Java 5 broke a tiny proportion of existing Java code that used "enum" as identifier.  This caused a bit of angst. So when they introduced `var` in Java 10, they made it "reserved type name" rather than a full keyword.

2 - At at least, I assume that they couldn't. If they could have done it, I think that they *would* have done it in the past 25 years or so.  Most people agree that Java array initialization is a bit clunky.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for those explanations. The part about having to deal with legacy syntax VS being free to simplify it on new features is really convincing.